# How to optimize Bootstrap Input Tags With a jQuery Date picker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, input, datepicker, tags

I have implement a Date picker. so that when I select a year from a date picker, selected year need to be appear as a tag inside the given input field

Code

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <form id="sbYearRevForm" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Year(s)<span style="color: red"> *</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <!-- <input type="tel" pattern='\d{9}'  id="msisdn" name="msisdn" placeholder="Subscriber No.(77xxxxxxx)" class="form-control input-sm" required> -->
                <input type="text" id="yearPicker" name="years" class="form-control input-sm" data-role="tagsinput" required>   
            </div>
        </div>
```

relevant jQuery functions as follows .

```
$('#yearPicker').tagsinput({
    typeaheadjs: {
       minViewMode: 2,
       format: 'yyyy',
       multidate: true,
       endDate: '+0y',
       startDate: '2016'
    }
});
$('.bootstrap-tagsinput input[type="text"]').datepicker({
    minViewMode: 2,
    format: 'yyyy',
    multidate: true,
    endDate: '+0y',
    startDate: '2016',
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        $('#yearPicker').tagsinput('add', dateText);
  }
});
```

When i implement this two issues found.

1. Usually in a tag there is a little x button at the right top corner to remove it. according to the my code it has missed.
2. According to the requirement tags need to be appear inside the input text area. but it has came to the out side.

Please see the attached screenshot below. Can anyone suggest me to overcome this issue? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this. what i had to do is add only the

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css
```

into my code.